# Notice: Undefined variable picture, gender

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

i'm getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: picture in C:\Users\Raj\PhpstormProjects\comment03\Wall\wall-functions.php on line 36

Notice: Undefined variable: picture in C:\Users\Raj\PhpstormProjects\comment03\Wall\wall-functions.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined variable: gender in C:\Users\Raj\PhpstormProjects\comment03\Wall\wall-functions.php on line 40
```

I've downloded a php wall script from now as i run program after connecting database it's giving me this error.. please help what should i do now?

here is my `wall-functions.php` code:

```
<?php
$path = 'http://yepinol.com/wall/';

if(!function_exists('getUserImg')) {

        function getUserImg($user_id = ''){

            $username_get = mysql_query("SELECT picture,gender from member where member_id=".$user_id." order by member_id desc limit 1");
            while ($name = @mysql_fetch_array($username_get))
            {
                $picture = $name['picture'];
                $gender = $name['gender'];
            }

            $imageUser = 'pics/'.$picture;

            if (!file_exists($imageUser) || $picture=='')  
            {
                if($gender == 'm')
                $imageUser = 'pics/no-image-m.png';
                else
                $imageUser = 'pics/no-image-f.png';
            }

            return  $imageUser;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare `$picture` and `$gender` outside/before the while loop.

Comment: as you said i did this, and that error msg disappeared but when i tried to share something it's not showing..... :(

Comment: @user3553704 I don't really understand what is not showing but you can debug your code by checking if `$picture` and `$gender` have values.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<?php
$path = 'http://yepinol.com/wall/';
$picture =''; // Declare variable
$gender = ''; // Declare variable

if(!function_exists('getUserImg')) {

        function getUserImg($user_id = ''){

            $username_get = mysql_query("SELECT picture,gender from member where member_id=".$user_id." order by member_id desc limit 1");
            while ($name = @mysql_fetch_array($username_get))
            {
                $picture = $name['picture'];
                $gender = $name['gender'];
            }

            $imageUser = 'pics/'.$picture;

            if (!file_exists($imageUser) || $picture=='')  
            {
                if($gender == 'm')
                $imageUser = 'pics/no-image-m.png';
                else
                $imageUser = 'pics/no-image-f.png';
            }

            return  $imageUser;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

i think you are facing proble with [Scope of variable](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=1602.0)